# Creating types with restricted properties

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

There are occasions where the possible values of a type need to be restricted according to some properties. Example floats or math vectors are required to be normalized. Is it a good practice to create classes for these cases and use operator overload to switch between the types?

For example have a vector2 and vector2_normalized class where the operators of vector2_normalized that can change the length of the vector (+, -, scalar * and /, ..) return a vector2 instance and the others return a vector2_normalized instance. Then use implicit conversion to automatically change between the two. This way vectors which must be normalized can use this type and normalization errors are eliminated.

Comment: Please try to use pseudo code and even diagrams to explain abstract concepts. Properly laid out question is also one of the best ways to come to the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes

These "restrictions" you are talking about are called [class invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant) and a class is a way to construct a domain object to restrict it to be valid. It's one of the primary motivations for using classes.

Arno Lepsik recently gave an excellent talk at CppCon 2018 about this called ["Avoiding disasters with strongly typed C++"](https://youtu.be/1fwbG5TyI18)

John Lakos also gave an excellent talk about this at CppCon 2015 called ["Value semantics. It ain't about the syntax"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3xI1HJUy7Q)

A full answer to your question would be very long, so I hope this brief discussion is useful.

One great example of this is [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

If you've ever had to deal with programming scientific applications, then you know that dealing with units is a pain.

How do you ensure that operations between your data are valid? You don't want to add meters to feet, that's how you crash rockets. When your values become strongly typed with your units, such an operation becomes impossible *at compile time*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly why we have the whole concept of `private` members.
It exists to eliminate all errors that would occur due to invalid member values.
It does so by, instead of the member itself, exposing an interface (overloaded operators and functions) so you could change those members in a controlled manner, where internal values are adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is `std::string` and `std::filesystem::path`. But there is neither `std::uppercase_string` nor `std::russian_string` nor any other...

See if those restrictions make a huge difference to *the interface* of your particular class. If the restrictions allow some entirely new operation, unthinkable in the general class, then it certainly deserves a dedicated class with extended public interface.

And I would certainly say a resounding NO to disguising a meaningful operation as an implicit conversion. Even more so if the conversion is irreversible. Such conversion may look tempting, and it may well eliminate some current errors caused by neglect, but just as likely it may introduce entirely new errors if an unwanted conversion slipped in without you even noticing.

Otherwise the question is way too generic... I suppose there's no solution good for all cases. So you should compare pros and contras in each particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - echoing everything AndyG says about class invariants and domain objects - with one caveat.

Allowing *implicit* conversion between types risks your code accumulating silent conversions. It's often better to use an explicit conversion function instead. For example, with

```
vec2 fun_a();
vec2 fun_b(norm_vec2 const&);
vec2 fun_c(norm_vec2 const&);
```

you can write

```
norm_vec2 v = fun_c(fun_b(fun_a()));
```

and not notice the number of implicit conversions occurring. At least if the conversions are explicit, you can decide to write `norm_vec2` overloads of your functions, or to just template them on the vector type if it isn't important.